# In MS Outlook VBA, how can I test if a folder is for e-mails?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I want to run through all my Outlook folders and build a [Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table) of e-mails in each. But the code to add columns of e-mail properties to the table, such as:

```
Set oTable = oFolder.GetTable(sFilter)
oTable.Columns.Add ("SenderName")
```

fails on folders that don't hold e-mails, such as the folder `Calendar`.

I could check if the first item in the folder is an e-mail by checking its [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.class):

```
oFolder.Items.Item(1).class = olMail
```

But that cannot be a valid test because an e-mail folder can contain items that are not e-mails, such as a [`MeetingItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.meetingitem). If the first item in an e-mail folder happens to be a `MeetingItem`, then the above test would give a false negative on whether the folder is an e-mail folder.

So how can I test if a folder is an e-mail folder so I can know whether I can add e-mail properties to a table made from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Folder.DefaultItemType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.defaultitemtype) property which returns a constant from the [OlItemType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olitemtype) enumeration indicating the default Outlook item type contained in the folder.

Actually, Outlook folders may contain different type of items - mail, appointment, document, post and etc. The best what you could do is to check the default item type for the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot judge the folder type by one of its items - e.g., Deleted Items folder can contain **any** kind of item. Inbox usually contains `MailItem`, `ReportItem`, `MeetingItem` objects. Calendar folder only contains `AppointmentItem` objects, but Contacts folder can contain both `ContactItem` and `DistListItem` objects.

You might want to provide details what it is exactly you are trying to achieve.